# Making GenericType in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Im trying to make GenericType in c++ that i can pass to std::map
but it is to restrict i have to have getter to every type the genericType
support this can be complex has the types will grow . 
Is there any way to make it better if it can be without templates or boost but c++11 can be supported .

For example : 
//This is the GenericType which i need to make it more generic

```
enum types {
  INT_TYPE,
  STRING_TYPE,
  CUSTOM_TYPE
}

struct GenericType {
  GenericType(int i) {
    intVal = i
    m_Type = INT_TYPE;
  }

  GenericType(std::string s) {
    stringVal = s
    m_Type = STRING_TYPE;
  }

  GenericType(CustomType ct) {
    customTypeVal = ct
    m_Type = CUSTOM_TYPE;
  }

  CustomType getCustomType() { return customTypeVal; };
  std::string getStringType() { return stringVal; };
  int getIntType() { return intVal; };
  types getType() { return m_Type; };

private:
  types m_Type;
  std::string stringVal;
  int intVal;
  CustomType customTypeVal;
};

//Init the map

std::map<std::string, GenericType> ContainerMap;

ContainerMap["String"] = new GenericType("Foo");
ContainerMap["Int"] = new GenericType(111);
ContainerMap["CustomType"] =new  CustomType (customTypeObj);


//Somewhere in the app 

CustomType* pCustomType = ctmymap.find("String")->second;

if(pCustomType->getType() == STRING_TYPE) {
  //Do something with String 
}

CustomType* pCustomType = ctmymap.find("Int")->second;
if(pCustomType->getType() == INT_TYPE) {
  //Do something with int 
}
```

Thanks for the helpers !

Comment: You could consider [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/any.html), do you have to make it yourself, is it an assignment/homework?

Comment: `ctmymap.find('String')->second;` => `ctmymap.find("String")->second;` Also dereferencing the result of `find()` unchecked is a bad idea.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: Supposed you can provide some working code about what you already have, questions for improvement are better placed at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SergeyA: OP said C++11 :-(

Comment: Why are you using `new`.  This isn't C#, there is no need for the `new` keyword above.

Comment: "without templates" that not how you roll in C++